# Core Data Relationships - displaying only those values found in specific entities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

This is a simple question, however one that I cannot find the answer to.

I'm building an app that stores data on Projects and People, which is stored within a SQLite database using Core Data.

A project can have many people, however a person is only assigned to one project. I'm displaying the data in a Table View, which at the moment displays ALL the people stored in a database whenever you view any project - this is not ideal.

**I would like to only display those people who are part of that project.** How would I go about this programatically? is this done using filtering? for example:

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"People"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"people.name = someones name"];

    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];


    [self performFetch];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a predicate, which acts as a filter. See the docs on NSPredicate.

The predicate must refer to the project you are interested in.  From the small amount of code that you have shown, you might try something like this (the details depend on your own implementation).

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"people.project = %@", projectName"];
```

Comment: Both excellent answers Jim and A Salcedo, however Jim's answer made the most sense to me, thanks.

Comment: To add to this, would I treat the Core Data model as a database and create another attribute called projects within the People entity? or is there a better way of handling relationships

Comment: I should look at your entity structures first. I assumed that something like project is already part of your people entity. If you edit  your question showing the header file for your people entity, I might be able to give you an answer. Core Data implements a directed graph (another name for relational database, I think). So , yes, it is a datebase. Also, show your project entity (I assume there is one if project is a relationship property of your people entity.)

Comment: Jim, at the moment the only attributes I have in Person is first name and last name as this is an early version. Would I need to create a new attribute called project, as well as setup the relationships between the Project and Person entities? So when a new person is saved, the project referenced is also stored alongside them.

Comment: If you want to have project information in your database that you can tie people to, then, yes, you create a project entity and a relationship between project <-->> people (one-to-many probably). Or you can just use a string property with the project name, but that would not have the benefit of the relational database (or object graph). Good luck.

Comment: I think what you need to look into first is how you will be storing relationships first. That will give you a nice understanding on how you will access them. With core data, you have to specify the relationship the two entries from both entities have. So lets say you are storing a person, with first, last name, etc. and for the relationship you will store a pointer to the project object that will be stored in the project entity. Similar setup for one to many, except of course that it will be handled as a set of elements.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I will assume your storing routine is correct and you are setting up your relationship correctly.

Second of all, if you want to be fetching people in a specific project, the easiest way to do it might be to set up project as the entity for the fetch.

That way all you have to do is set up your predicate for the desired project, and from that managed object you should have an NSSet for the people within that project. From that set it is up to you how you want to handle the information.